# React Flux: Using same store for two different scripts

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am new to flux architecture. I am following facebook's flux todo example. But I want to do small modification. I wrote small react script which will get data from same store but will be rendered on different HTML tag. But when I am updating data from example then it's not rendering my newly generated script. Its still displaying the old count.
I wanted to ask that can I use same store for different react script? Where updates made on store from one script will be reflected on other script?
Here is the snapshot:
[image: Screen shot of front end]

The code is exact same as provided in facebook's github account. I am just adding new component in it. The code for new component is:

```
var React = require('react');
var TodoActions = require('../actions/TodoActions');
var TodoStore = require('../stores/TodoStore');

function getTodos() {
  return {
    allTodos: TodoStore.getAll()
  };
}

var SampleSection = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return getTodos();
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        TodoStore.addChangeListener(this._onChanged);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        TodoStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChanged);
    },

    render: function() {
        var total = Object.keys(this.state.allTodos).length;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is sample count: {total}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    },

    _onChanged: function() {
        this.setState(getTodos());
    }
});

module.exports = SampleSection;
```

So I want to update sample count whenever I will add new task in todo.
Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Is this component a child of your main component?

Comment: @erichardson30 No. In main component we need to wrap everything inside div or any other tag(react DOM). But I want to place Sample count somewhere else in my HTML code. That's why I've different script for it.